# Drawing triangle in Canvas issue

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have photo with triangle/rectangle drawn moveable here:http://jsfiddle.net/b29hxxma/ Now i want replace photo with video but with moveable shape see here:http://jsfiddle.net/alwaysgreat/ez1orho1/ but somehow its not working.I tried lot and even able to draw shape but not making it moveable.Pls help.Code(got from somewhere) i used to draw shape but not making it moveable on video:

```
function draw() {
var v = document.getElementById("video1");
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(v, 5, 5, 260, 125);
ctx.clearRect(135, 92, 126, 34);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(135, 92, 126, 34);
ctx.fillStyle = 'pink';
ctx.fill();
setTimeout(function(){ draw(v,5, 5, 260, 125); }, 20);
}
draw();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a moveable rectangle over the video, you can use this code (adapted from your second JSFiddle link):

```
var v = document.getElementById("video1");
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var mouseX = 135;
var mouseY = 92;

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.drawImage(v, 5, 5, 260, 125);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(mouseX, mouseY, 126, 34);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'pink';
  ctx.fill();
  setTimeout(function(){ draw(v,5, 5, 260, 125); }, 20);
}


function findOffset(obj) {
  var curX = 0,
  curY = 0;
  if (obj.offsetParent) {
    do {
      curX += obj.offsetLeft;
      curY += obj.offsetTop;
    } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);

    return {
      x: curX,
      y: curY
    };
  }
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  var offset = findOffset(c);
  mouseX = event.pageX - offset.x;
  mouseY = event.pageY - offset.y;
}

draw();
```

The code will draw a rectangle over the top of the video at the mouse position. It works by saving the mouse position from the `onmousemove` function, and then when the draw function is called, it draws the rectangle at that location.

Comment: Oh my @gravityScore actually i have rectangle drawn over video,see here http://jsfiddle.net/alwaysgreat/omnmjm2q/ and want that rectangle to be moveable not the video itself.Pls suggest what edit should i do to do this.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood what you were after. I've updated the answer.